# Function isn't giving response

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
function findTriad(numbers, sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    const firstNumber = numbers[i];
    const newSum = sum - firstNumber;
    let startOfCheckIndex = i + 1;
    const endOfCheckIndex = numbers.length - 1;

    while (startOfCheckIndex < endOfCheckIndex) {
      const possibleAnswer =
        numbers[startOfCheckIndex] + numbers[endOfCheckIndex];
      if (possibleAnswer === newSum) {
        return [
          numbers[i],
          numbers[startOfCheckIndex],
          numbers[endOfCheckIndex]
        ];
      } else if (sum < newSum) {
        startOfCheckIndex++;
      }
    }
  }
  return ["N/A"];
}

function logFindTriad(numbers, sum) {
  const answer = findTriad(numbers, sum);

  console.log("Sum required: " + sum);
  console.log("Numbers given: " + numbers.join(", "));
  console.log("Found: " + answer.join(", ") + "\n");
}

logFindTriad([10, 15, 3, 7], 20);
```

Does anyone know why this code isn't giving me any value back?
It is supposed to give me back [10, 3, 7] if you find any errors or areas to improve on my code please tell me even if it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Is the top section of code the `findTriad` function? Also when you say 'give back', do you mean it should return the values, or console log them?

Comment: `findTriad` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: Please complete your code. Your for loop is not in any function and ends with a curly bracket

Answer (score 1):

The first time the code enters the `while (startOfCheckIndex < endOfCheckIndex) {`
startOfCheckIndex  is 1 and endOfCheckIndex is 3
That means `possibleAnswer` is 10 + 7 = 17.
newSum is 10 and sum is 20
That means that neither

`if (possibleAnswer === newSum) {`

or

`} else if (sum < newSum) {`

are true. Resulting in startOfCheckIndex never getting changed.

In turn, `while (startOfCheckIndex < endOfCheckIndex) {` will always be true, resulting in an infinite loop.

You need to add an `else` clause or some other leaving condition.

Here is an example to demonstrate the issue.

```js
let loopRestriction = 100

function findTriad(numbers, sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    const firstNumber = numbers[i];
    const newSum = sum - firstNumber;
    let startOfCheckIndex = i + 1;
    const endOfCheckIndex = numbers.length - 1;

    while (startOfCheckIndex < endOfCheckIndex) {

      const possibleAnswer = numbers[startOfCheckIndex] + numbers[endOfCheckIndex];
      if (loopRestriction-- <= 0) {
        console.log("Stuck in while loop for atleast 100 iterations.")
        break
      }
      console.log({
        startOfCheckIndex,
        endOfCheckIndex,
        possibleAnswer,
        sum,
        newSum
      })

      if (possibleAnswer === newSum) {
        return [
          numbers[i],
          numbers[startOfCheckIndex],
          numbers[endOfCheckIndex]
        ];
      } else if (sum < newSum) {
        startOfCheckIndex++;
      }
    }
  }
  return ["N/A"];
}

function logFindTriad(numbers, sum) {
  const answer = findTriad(numbers, sum);

  console.log("Sum required: " + sum);
  console.log("Numbers given: " + numbers.join(", "));
  console.log("Found: " + answer.join(", ") + "\n");
}

logFindTriad([10, 15, 3, 7], 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, function findTriad you are not defined
- Then, your code has execute to `else` statement because condition in `if` and `else if` is wrong so you go to `infinity loop` (because you don't update value of `startOfCheckIndex` after loop, you can debug your code and find a true way to give condition in `if else`statement. I can give code sample [here](https://repl.it/repls/MoccasinHungryUtility)

Happy coding !